# visual studio 2017 doesn't accept minify css

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I Minified a css file with https://cssminifier.com/ but when I want to copy the `minify` result to `visual studio 2017` it is not `minify` and it's the same as befor .

there is a lot of `spaces` , `new lines` and ....

but when I tried with visual studio 2015 , It was ok and worked fine .

is there any special setting ?

an example of code is :

```
.animated {
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
z-index: 100
}

.animated.infinite {
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite
}
```

Comment: Turn off auto formatting - see here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/12/26/change-css-formatting/

Comment: auto formatting didn't work so only way i have found is to paste in the minified css and then click undo (Ctrl + Z)

Comment: Thank you so much @SSED. It did work. You are almost there for VS 2017. I posted the updated answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Slight changes to @SSED's answer on Sep 22 2017 to account for changes in Visual Studio 2017.

Please navigate to Menu:  Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> CSS -> Advanced -> Formatting-> Format on Paste : **Off**

[image: Options Panel to turn off automatic CSS formatting on paste in Visual Studio 2017]